# How to automate the clicking of 'Allow/Block' button in webrtc for microphone permission pop-up using selenium in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to automate the event of clicking at 'Allow/Block' permissions of microphone in webrtc using Selenium. Since these pop-up alerts are not a part of browser elements, so clicking through XPath would not work. So I tried to automate it by using the keyboard shortcuts to Allow/Block microphone, selecting the Allow/Block buttons by Tab key and pressing Enter.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab).Perform();
action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter).Perform();
```

But SendKeys does not work. Is there any other way to interact with these alert buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the AutoIt for interacting with non html content?

https://www.autoitscript.com

Autoit is a useful scripting tool where you can automate simple actions in windows platform.